# How do I make jmeter use the different hostname/port for different threads of same test plan

Tags: jmeter, test-plan

In my test scenario I have to test 2 urls with different host and port under same test plan. Is it possible to do so

Answer (score 1):

You can make variable as property and send to jmeter script

Add to Test Plan In User define variables 2 rows:

baseUrl with Value ${__P(baseUrl,localhost)}

port with Value ${__P(port,8080)}

localhost and 8080 are default values you can change it

and when you execute add the values you want e.g.:

jmeterw.cmd ... -JbaseUrl=192.168.0.33 -Jport=80

Answer (score 1):

1. Define your host and port combinations in a CSV `endpoints.csv` file like:

   ```
   somehost,someport
   someotherhost, someotherport
   ```

   and put the CSV file to the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
2. Add [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to your test plan and configure it like:

   [image: JMeter CSV]
3. Set HTTP Request sampler to use `${host}` and `${port}` variables defined via the CSV Data Set Config

   [image: JMeter HTTP From CSV]

That's it, on each iteration (or virtual user hit) the next line will be picked up from the `endpoints.csv` file.

See [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) article for more information on parameterising JMeter tests using CSV files.

Comment: Thank you. I have created the variable and passed to host and port